# Add Class to Div when another div appears in viewport

Tags: jquery

Please see my JS Fiddle...

Not sure why this is not working simply trying to add a class when my hero div appears in the viewport.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hero').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
      if (visible == true) {
        // element is now visible in the viewport
        $('.home').addClass('test');
      } else {
        // element has gone out of viewport
         $('.home').removeClass('test');
      }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/franclowe/KqQds/

Comment: define ``not working``. Is your event triggered? Are you getting any console messages?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://github.com/schaenk/jquery-in-viewport

```
if ($('.hero').inViewport()) {
    $('.home').addClass('test');
else {
    $('.home').removeClass('test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle with working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zcZuD/1/

Things I have done to fix this:

1. Actually add jQuery and the inview plugin as dependencies (don't use direct linking to github, though, it's not a CDN)
2. Fixed your css so `.test p` is red.